# Build a GUI frame but it shows blank

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

this is a frame viewer class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Viewer
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
{
   JFrame frame = new Frame();

   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setTitle("Shinkei-suijaku");
   frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

this is a frame class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Frame extends JFrame
{
   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 800;
   private final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
   private ImageIcon image1;
   private JLabel label1;
   private ImageIcon image2;
   private JLabel label2;
   private ImageIcon image3;
   private JLabel label3;
   private JComboBox combo;
   private JTextField textField1;
   private JTextField textField2;
   private JButton button;
   private JPanel ChoosePanel;
   private JPanel ImagePanel;
   public Frame()
   {  

      createImagePanel();
      createChoosePanel();
      add(ChoosePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(ImagePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
      setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
   }
      //create a image panel for images
      public void createImagePanel()
      {
      ImagePanel = new JPanel();
      ImagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
      image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("cover.jpg"));
      label1 = new JLabel(image1);
      ImagePanel.add(label1);
      ImagePanel.add(label1);
      ImagePanel.add(label1);
      ImagePanel.add(label1);
      ImagePanel.add(label1);
      ImagePanel.add(label1);
      }
      //create a panel for combobox and textfield
      public void createChoosePanel()
      {
      ChoosePanel = new JPanel();
      ChoosePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
      combo =new JComboBox();
      combo.addItem("reveal");
      combo.addItem("cover");
      combo.addItem("done");
      ChoosePanel.add(combo);

      textField1 = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
      textField2 = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
      ChoosePanel.add(textField1);
      ChoosePanel.add(textField2);

      button = new JButton("check");
      ChoosePanel.add(button);

      }




      //Frame uses BorderLayout by default


      }
```

This is a part of the memory game program. First we need to build a GUI frame which has images , button and text field. It can be compiled, but when I run it, it only shows the blank frame.And I don't know the problem.

Comment: 1) `ImagePanel.add(label1);
      ImagePanel.add(label1); ..` Each component can be added to a GUI exactly once. What did you expect to achieve by adding it 6 times? 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: 1. method `public class Frame extends JFrame` should be method `public class MyFrame extends JFrame`, because there is `java.awt.Frame` defined in standard APIs as container

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can run you application and get the GUI as the picture shows.

but I have got one NullPointer exception on

```
image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("cover.jpg"));
```

please make sure your **image file** is in correct path.

Comment: But I cannot get the GUI which is really strange, I use sciTE to program